# Symbolic breakpoint for when dispatch_async is called with a specific queue

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, lldb

I'm debugging an issue in my project involving grand central dispatch. In debugging this, it would be really helpful to have a way of being notified when work is dispatched to a specific queue.

Is there some way of setting a symbolic breakpoint on `dispatch_async` with a condition that could check whether the dispatch queue argument is the same as some other queue that I have access to?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to set a conditional breakpoint. (I haven't done conditions on queues, I'm making the assumption here that pointer equality will Just Work™.)

First get the address of the queue you want, let's say it's `0x12345678`. Then create a breakpoint:

```
breakpoint set -n dispatch_async -c '$register == 0x12345678'
```

Replace `$register` with an expression specific to the architecture.

*Updated to show `$arg1` from [Jim Ingham's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470217/symbolic-breakpoint-for-when-dispatch-async-is-called-with-a-specific-queue/30497387#comment49150550_30497387)*

Simulator

- x86: `*(id*)($esp+4)`
- x86-64: `$arg1` (aka `$rdi`)

Device

- armv7: `$arg1` (aka `$r0`)
- arm64: `$arg1` (aka `$x0`)

Comment: Note, for all the architectures that pass the first argument in registers (i.e. all but x86) lldb has the "$arg1" alias register name, which translates to whichever register is used to pass the first argument.

Comment: Thanks! Is that inherited from gdb? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Not inherited from gdb, we made this up.  Doesn't look like it is documented anywhere, I'll see if I can find a good place to do this.

Comment: I dug around and see that it can be found via `register read -A`, along with $fp/$sp/$pc/etc. I tweeted about it and it was news to many. Definitely worth documenting somewhere, it got a lot of interest.

Comment: Just noting that since Apple dropped 32-bit binary support the $arg1 syntax is now correct for both simulator and device architectures.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the label on your queue you can just set a conditional breakpoint on a string match within the block being executed.  Sometime's I'll just log it like this though.

```
if (!strcmp(dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL), dispatch_queue_get_label(myDispatchQueue)){
    printf("Booyah!\n");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that'll only work for cases where my code is the only one submitting blocks to the dispatch queue. I need a solution that can detect cases when a block is submitted to a queue from code that I don't have access to the source for. For example, maybe I want to set a break point that'll stop whenever `dispatch_async` is called on the main queue, even when it is being called from one of Apple's libraries.