# Using of symbolic breakpoints for child classes in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, uiview

I have a class `SomeClass` which is inherited from `UIView` and I want to track where its method `setFrame:` was called.

In case of `UIView` I could add a symbolic breakpoint with value `-[UIView setFrame:]` but I can't do the same for my own class - it is simply never called/stopped on a breakpoint. And of course I can't use `-[UIView setFrame:]` because it will be called extra times. How to solve this issue?

I could override `setFrame:` in my own class but in this case I don't need symbolic breakpoint and it's better to use usual breakpoint instead. But in this case I also need to add some changes in my own class and it is not very appropriate for me.

Comment: What about if you use Xcode to set the breakpoint (i.e. clicking in the gutter on the left of the method)?

Comment: **facepalm**  Must I click on the left of each call of this method?

Comment: I don't understand what is going on here; I thought I had replied to your second comment but I can no longer see it.  I also don't understand why you are asking me if I'm silly.

Comment: In general I describe a task which is hard to perform fully manually and ask how to automate it at least partially. Then you "suggest" the same fully manual way I described in a question. How should I react?

Comment: My comment was intended to see if the breakpoint actually worked if you used the UI in order to see if the issue was related to how you specify the breakpoint.  I was not suggesting that you set your breakpoints this way during your normal workflow.  I was also suggesting you set the breakpoint on the method, not on the callers of the method.

Comment: Again read the question more attentively please - it was already described. Again if you mean the method of the `UIView` class then it will be called **too often**, if you mean the method inside my class I **must to edit** my class to add at least a declaration of this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to put a breakpoint on -[UIView setFrame:] but only have it stop when "self" is an object of class SomeClass.  You can do that with a breakpoint condition.  Something like:

```
(int) strcmp("SomeClass", (const char *)class_getName((id)[(id) $arg1 class])) == 0
```

The only trick here is that `$arg1` is an alias for the register that holds the first argument, and in ObjC methods the first argument is always `self`.  Note, the $arg1 register alias is only defined for architectures that use registers for argument passing; in particular 32-bit x86 does not pass arguments this way.  The following answer has a good description of how to get the first argument on most common architectures:

[Symbolic breakpoint for when dispatch_async is called with a specific queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470217/symbolic-breakpoint-for-when-dispatch-async-is-called-with-a-specific-queue/30497387#30497387)

This may slow down your process a bit, since it will stop at every call to  `[UIView setFrame]` but there's no good way to avoid that except as you suggest to override setFrame: and then stop there.

I am also a bit obnoxiously overdoing the casting here.  We don't have debug information for many of these functions, so you have to tell the debugger what their return types are.

By the way, the lldb command line also has a "break on selector" type which will break on all implementations of a given selector.  There's no UI way to call this up, but in the console you can do:

```
(lldb) break set -S setFrame:
```

So you could set a breakpoint on ALL setFrame: methods, and then add the same condition (you can do this by passing the `-c` flag to the `break set` command.  If this breakpoint ends up matching too many functions, you can disable individual hits by looking up their indices with `break list` and then disabling them one by one by using the `bkpt.loc` form you'll see in the `break list` output..

Comment: It seems that you have fully understood me. But I get `error: use of undeclared identifier 'self'`. Maybe should I additionally do something more?

Comment: Yes, you can't use "self" since you are setting this breakpoint in code that has no debug info.  I used $arg1 above, which is lldb's notation for the first argument passing register.  That works because self will be passed in as the first argument, and I'm stopping at the beginning of the function when self hasn't been copied out of that register yet.

Comment: Sorry but I still can't understand how to use it. I get the same error: `error: use of undeclared identifier '$arg1'`. How to use it correctly?

Comment: Are you debugging a 32 bit x86 binary?  32 bit x86 doesn't use registers for argument passing, it passes on the stack.  So in that case, you should use: *(id*)($esp+4) rather than $arg1.  This question was discussed already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470217/symbolic-breakpoint-for-when-dispatch-async-is-called-with-a-specific-queue/30497387#30497387

Comment: Almost. I followed your link and used `*(id*)($esp+4)`. Could you add the info about these various args to your answer? So I could approve it as an answer.

Comment: Just noting that since Apple dropped 32-bit binary support the $arg1 syntax is now correct for both simulator and device architectures.