# Get pointer to self in LLDB?

Tags: conditional-statements, breakpoints, self, lldb

I want to create a breakpoint in xCode which uses `LLDB` and checks the current object class in condition section.

The problem is `LLDB` doesn't allow to use `self` to get a class. How to solve this problem? Maybe through other commands? For example, `bt` command output contains correct classname but it seems it is not allowed in `LLDB` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume this is related to:

[Using of symbolic breakpoints for child classes in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403719/using-of-symbolic-breakpoints-for-child-classes-in-xcode/31527538?noredirect=1#comment51025585_31527538)

The problem comes if your breakpoint is in code with no debug information (like in system libraries.)  The debugger knows nothing about self in this context, and you have to give it more help.  In the case of `self`, you know that it was passed into a method call as the first argument, so you can use `$arg1` to get at the value.

Comment: Note also that this trick only works when you are at the very beginning of a function.  After that the argument passing register has almost surely been reused.

Comment: and `$arg1` isn't available for 32-bit x86 code -- most commonly used when running in the 32-bit iOS simulator on the mac.